# Can dompdf + file_get_contents be used safely?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF to let users of a web app create PDF invoices based on an HTML template they have complete control over.

We have disabled file_get_contents() on our server, but can enable it if we want to.

My questions is, can file_get_contents() be used securely to allow the rendering (and remote or local? loading of images) with DOMPDF?

What are the security pitfalls here?

Answer (score 1):

There's really not enough information here to answer for certain whether or not enabling `file_get_contents()` would be secure on your system. For that we would have to know what other PHP apps are on the system and/or if that function is being used anywhere else and in what manner.

That being said, if you consider solely how DOMPDF itself uses `file_get_contents()` you have no cause to worry. DOMPDF uses the function to pull in content of any externally-referenced file (i.e. css or image). DOMPDF is explicit in how it handles any content so a user shouldn't be able to cause any extra harm just because the content is external from the HTML document.

Short of an exploit in `file_get_contents()` I don't believe enabling the function will suddenly make DOMPDF insecure. The typical concern is that the function is used in a way that could make it vulnerable to nefarious activities (such as information disclosure attacks). This is something DOMPDF was vulnerable to in the past that has been addressed as of 0.5.2 (so long as you are configured securely ... e.g. don't set `DOMPDF_CHROOT` to `/`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. We are concerned about opening up file_get_contents() on our server, as this would give hackers a way to start information disclosure attacks as you mentioned. The only reason we would open up the function is to be able to use images in DOMPDF. Do you need any more info ?

Comment: If you're not using the function anywhere else, and if you are using dompdf 0.5.2 or greater, then I believe you should be ok. If you're not using dompdf.php you can remove that file for greater security since that was the source of information disclosure in earlier version of dompdf.

Comment: Thanks Brian, how about hackers that could potentially try and use the function on our server after trying to gain access with a php shell of some sorts? We're not using the function ourselves anywhere else but are concerned about opening it up on our machines in general

Comment: A bad guy would have to find some way to run PHP code on your server first. As long as the function isn't used in an exploitable way it should be safe to enable. You're not using the function anywhere else. And I don't know of any exploits in dompdf (though there are some weaknesses depending on your configuration).

Comment: Of course, this all assumes there are no other exploits on your system. So I can't say for certain that your server is safe or that enabling that function is safe. A statement like that would require some kind of audit.